# MS SQL IF Statement Executing IF and ELSE Blocks

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, if-statement

All, I have the following query

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name 
               FROM sys.databases 
               WHERE name = N'Report')
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @DatabasePath NVARCHAR(1000);
        SET @DatabasePath = (SELECT ResultMessage + '\' 
                             FROM [Admin]..[Process]);
        EXEC ispCREATEDB N'Report', @DatabasePath, N'10MB', N'20%'
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN 
        IF EXISTS (SELECT *  
                   FROM Report.sys.objects 
                   WHERE name = N'FatalErrSumm' AND type = N'U')
        BEGIN 
            DROP TABLE [Report]..[FatalErrSumm];
            CREATE TABLE [Report]..[FatalErrSumm]
            (
                [MDF] NVARCHAR(255) NULL,
                [Error] INT NULL,
            );
        END
    END
```

This checks if `Report` exists from a different databse; if it does not exist it creates it, if it does, it checks if table `FatalErrSumm` exists and if it does it drops and recreates it.

The problems is that it seems to be executing both possiblities of the `IF NOT EXISTS` block and giving the error

```
Msg 2702, Level 16, State 2, Line 24
Database 'Report' does not exist.
```

when the database `Report` does not exist. So it should never be entering the `ELSE` block, however it seems to be. This is very basic stuff, but I cannot for the life of me spot the error, **What am I doing wrong here?**

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bypass it using a dynamic sql

```
 IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name  
               FROM sys.databases  
               WHERE name = N'Report') 
    BEGIN 
        DECLARE @DatabasePath NVARCHAR(1000); 
        SET @DatabasePath = (SELECT ResultMessage + '\'  
                             FROM [Admin]..[Process]); 
        EXEC ispCREATEDB N'Report', @DatabasePath, N'10MB', N'20%' 
    END 
ELSE IF DB_ID('Report') IS NOT NULL
    EXEC
    (
        'BEGIN  
        IF EXISTS (SELECT *   
                   FROM Report.sys.objects  
                   WHERE name = N''FatalErrSumm'' AND type = N''U'') 
        BEGIN  
            DROP TABLE [Report]..[FatalErrSumm]; 
            CREATE TABLE [Report]..[FatalErrSumm] 
            ( 
                [MDF] NVARCHAR(255) NULL, 
                [Error] INT NULL, 
            ); 
        END 
        END'
        );
```

Comment: There is no reason to use dynamic SQL here. Why do you think I should make it dynamic? Thanks for your time.

Comment: If the database report does not exist when you run the code you will get error. Only way is to bypass it using dynamic sql.

Comment: Someone is presuming that this code exists in a procedure. The OP talks about 'a query' not a procedure. You NEED dynamic sql if it is a procedure otherwise, no you don't need it.

Answer (score 1):

I think  dynamic sql is the good solution for that. because in compile time compiler checked that the database "report" is not exist in you server.

Answer (score -1):

If the report is offline I think this failes, check if the database is online /attached. There is flag for this in the sys.databases table.

Also do not put your statements in the ELSE. If you enter the 'THEN' part you create the database. After that check if it is created. Than ALWAYS check for you FATALERRSUMM table and not from the IF.

pseudo code:

```
if (not exists database) -- watch it not exists is really NOT EXISTS not just not online
    create the database

if (exists database and not online)
    put online the database

if (not exists database or not online database)
    throw error

if (exists table fatalerrsum)
      drop table
      create table
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'online'. If the database is not attached it will not appear as part of the first test. The check for the 'FatalErrSumm' always occurs if the database is found, I don't really understand what you mean in the second paragraph. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Don't know why anyone wants to downvote a working solution?
a) it is possible to detach a database
b) it is possible to take a database offline (right mouse and so...)
select name, state_desc from sys.databases

Comment: The second paragraph:
You check if the database exists, if not you create it, but you don't create the table.
If the databases exists you drop and recreate a table.
So the end-condition depends on the existence of the database. I think it is good practice to strive to exactly 1 end-condition.